# Children's fantasy book about monsters and monster killers, the main character has one purple eye and one blue eye

Tags: story-identification

I recall the plot contained monsters, who have certain powers. The main character has one purple eye and one blue eye which harm people and heal people respectively. They were also connected with his emotions.

The main character's mother killed his father, because she was a monster killer, a different sort of creature which cannot contain murderous impulses. She left him alive because he possesses several attributes of monster killers.

Additionally the book was near Simon Thorn and the Wolves Den on the shelf.

The cover showed the main character, a blonde boy with a blue eye and a purple eye, standing in a reddish forest.

Comment: Just based on the eye colors, could this be "Lunatic" by Ted Dekker and Kaci Hill?

Comment: Right kind of a title, and monster killers, at https://www.goodreads.com/en/book/show/39947245, but no dichromatic eyes.