# Novel where a girl disguised as a boy fights monsters, and only people under 18 can fight

Tags: story-identification, novel

What book has a girl protagonist who pretends to be a boy and fights monsters? She's been taught that only people under 18 can fight monsters, but she learns that she's been lied to and that anyone can fight. There is also a librarian who is a witch.

The protagonist rides a flying animal, and her mentor is named leo
.

Comment: Welcome to [scifi.se] SE! To increase your chances of getting a good answer, please [edit] your question and add more details, such as when you read the book and what works you have already checked and ruled out. For more tips on how to improve your question, take a look at our [guide on asking identification questions](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9335/7957).

Comment: It sounds similar to the plot of [Monster Hunter Legends of the Guild](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=a34v2S8cKwM). I wonder if the game was originally adapted from a book or if a book was written from the game.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found it: ***[Ottilie Colter and the Narroway Hunt](https://www.goodreads.com/en/book/show/39947245)*** (2018) by Rhiannon Williams. It's the first book in the *[The Narroway](https://www.goodreads.com/series/259083-the-narroway-trilogy)* trilogy.

> A young girl must pretend to be a boy to rescue her brother from a secret order of monster hunters.
>
> Ottilie Colter and her brother, Gully, have always fended for themselves. So when Gully goes missing one night, Ottilie sets out to find him – and soon makes a horrible discovery. Gully has been forcibly recruited by the Narroway Hunt, a secretive male-only organisation that hunts savage, blight-spreading monsters called ‘dredretches’.
>
> Disguising herself as a boy, Ottilie infiltrates the Hunt – but quickly realises that taking her brother home won't be easy. Trapped in the heart of the dredretch-infested Narroway, it's impossibly dangerous for them to leave. But as she trains to become a Huntsman alongside her brother, hoping for a chance to escape, how long can she keep her true identity a secret?

Comment: Glad you found it. We'd be grateful if you'd mark your answer as [accepted](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer), which is this site's way of showing that a query has been solved to the querent's satisfaction. You can mark an answer as accepted by clicking on the check mark beneath the voting buttons, however, as this is a self-answer, you'll need to wait until the question is 48 hours old before the site will let you do that.

Comment: I was hoping this might also answer https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/279561/childrens-fantasy-book-about-monsters-and-monster-killers-the-main-character-h but it seems the details differ too much.